# WPF: Accessing children elements from a base class

Tags: wpf, xaml, inheritance, controls

I'm trying to create add some custom behaviors to a `ScrollViewer` in WPF / XAML.  Specifically, the `ScrollViewer` should scroll to the top any time the `Thumb` in the `VerticalScrollBar` is clicked.  Likewise, it should scroll to the left any time the `Thumb` in the `HorizontalScrollBar` is clicked.

I would think the easiest way of doing this would be to create a new class that inherits from `ScrollViewer`, and then subscribes to the `MouseDoubleClick` event on the `VerticalScrollBar`'s `Thumb` and on the `HorizontalScrollBar`'s `Thumb`.

For example:

```
public class DoubleClickScrollViwer : ScrollViewer
{
   public DoubleClickScrollViwer()
      : base()
   {
      //Find the Horizontal and Vertical scroll bars.  Subscribe to the thumb's double click.
   }

   void VerticalScrollBarThumb_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
      this.ScrollToTop();
   }

   void HorizontalScrollBarThumb_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
      this.ScrollToLeft();
   }
}
```

I can't seem to find a way to drill down to the children from the `DoubleClickScrollViewer`.  How can I drill down to the children?  Or is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: What children are you talking about?

Comment: youscrollbar.children[0] will return first child control of your scrollbar.

Comment: @Ganesh The default Template for a ScrollViewer consists of a grid, and inside that grid is a Rectange, a ScrollContentPresenter, and two ScrollBars.